# Data frame from multiple XML files

Tags: r, xml, dataframe, xml2

I have a folder with multiple XML files. All the files have the same basic structure. However, each file actually contains data related to a single entity distributed among 16 parent nodes. Some nodes have children, some even have grandchildren, and some great-grandchildren.

I want to create a data frame from multiple files with only selected nodes/children/grandchildren.

As a first step, I read a single XML file as a list. Then ran a few lines of code to get the required data into a vector. Eventually, converted the vector to a dataframe, like I want one.

This the code:

```
library(xml2)
library(tidyverse)

x = as_list(read_xml("ACTRN12605000003673.xml"))

tmp = c(ACTR_Number = as.character(x$ANZCTR_Trial$actrnumber),
         primary_sponsor_type = as.character(x$ANZCTR_Trial$sponsorship$primarysponsortype),
         primary_sponsor_name = as.character(x$ANZCTR_Trial$sponsorship$primarysponsorname),
         primary_sponsor_address = as.character(x$ANZCTR_Trial$sponsorship$primarysponsoraddress),
         primary_sponsor_country = as.character(x$ANZCTR_Trial$sponsorship$primarysponsorcountry),
         funding_source_type = as.character(x$ANZCTR_Trial$sponsorship$fundingsource$fundingtype),
         funding_source_name = as.character(x$ANZCTR_Trial$sponsorship$fundingsource$fundingname),
         funding_source_address = as.character(x$ANZCTR_Trial$sponsorship$fundingsource$fundingaddress),
         funding_source_country = as.character(x$ANZCTR_Trial$sponsorship$fundingsource$fundingcountry),
         secondary_sponsor_type = as.character(x$ANZCTR_Trial$sponsorship$secondarysponsor$sponsortype),
         secondary_sponsor_name = as.character(x$ANZCTR_Trial$sponsorship$secondarysponsor$sponsorname),
         secondary_sponsor_address = as.character(x$ANZCTR_Trial$sponsorship$secondarysponsor$sponsoraddress),
         secondary_sponsor_country = as.character(x$ANZCTR_Trial$sponsorship$secondarysponsor$sponsorcountry))
tmp = as.list(tmp)
tmp = as.data.frame(tmp)
```

For the next step, I tried to work with 2 XML files together. I tried the following code to read two files simultaneously. However, beyond that, I don't know how to go ahead.

```
all_files = list.files(pattern=".xml", path = getwd(), full.names = TRUE)
x = lapply(all_files, read_xml)
class(x)
```

Sample files [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Y0rwBJkirZWt0zBdIVxNDaOrpdBkOGly?usp=sharing)

Comment: We cannot access your sample files.

Comment: @ekoam, you may try now. It should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can encapsulate your data gathering process into a function. Since each XML file seems to represent one row in your desired output dataframe, we can use `purrr::map_dfr` to construct the data rowwise. I slightly modified your code. See below:

```
get_row_data <- function(file_name) {
  xml <- xml2::read_xml(file_name)
  read_text <- \(x, xpath) rvest::html_elements(x, xpath = xpath) |> rvest::html_text(TRUE) 
  xpaths <- c(
    ACTR_Number = "/ANZCTR_Trial/actrnumber", 
    primary_sponsor_type = "/ANZCTR_Trial/sponsorship/primarysponsortype", 
    primary_sponsor_name = "/ANZCTR_Trial/sponsorship/primarysponsorname", 
    primary_sponsor_address = "/ANZCTR_Trial/sponsorship/primarysponsoraddress", 
    primary_sponsor_country = "/ANZCTR_Trial/sponsorship/primarysponsorcountry",
    funding_source_type = "/ANZCTR_Trial/sponsorship/fundingsource/fundingtype",
    funding_source_name = "/ANZCTR_Trial/sponsorship/fundingsource/fundingname",
    funding_source_address = "/ANZCTR_Trial/sponsorship/fundingsource/fundingaddress",
    funding_source_country = "/ANZCTR_Trial/sponsorship/fundingsource/fundingcountry",
    secondary_sponsor_type = "/ANZCTR_Trial/sponsorship/secondarysponsor/sponsortype",
    secondary_sponsor_name = "/ANZCTR_Trial/sponsorship/secondarysponsor/sponsorname",
    secondary_sponsor_address = "/ANZCTR_Trial/sponsorship/secondarysponsor/sponsoraddress",
    secondary_sponsor_country = "/ANZCTR_Trial/sponsorship/secondarysponsor/sponsorcountry"
  )
  x <- read_text(xml, paste0(xpaths, collapse = " | "))
  names(x) <- names(xpaths)
  as_tibble(as.list(x))
}

all_files <- list.files(pattern = ".xml", path = getwd(), full.names = TRUE)
purrr::map_dfr(all_files, get_row_data)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  ACTR_Number         primary_sponsor_~ primary_sponsor_n~ primary_sponsor_~ primary_sponsor~ funding_source_~ funding_source_~
  <chr>               <chr>             <chr>              <chr>             <chr>            <chr>            <chr>           
1 ACTRN12605000003673 Hospital          Barwon Health      "272-322 Ryrie S~ Australia        Commercial sect~ Astra Zeneca    
2 ACTRN12605000025639 Other Collaborat~ Australian Gastro~ "88 Mallett St\n~ Australia        Commercial sect~ Roche Products ~
# ... with 6 more variables: funding_source_address <chr>, funding_source_country <chr>, secondary_sponsor_type <chr>,
#   secondary_sponsor_name <chr>, secondary_sponsor_address <chr>, secondary_sponsor_country <chr>
```

Answer (score 0):

R supports list within lists. When you define a list, which will contain all your tmp lists. Then after putting all files in this list you can make a data frame or tibble. Then your tibble contains columns with lists(tmp). You then can address them with map functions from library(purrr)

Comment: Can you please suggest some readings? I'm getting errors while converting a long list to either tibble or a dataframe.

Comment: This seems interesting:
https://medium.com/geekculture/reading-xml-files-in-r-3122c3a2a8d9